# Getting the same 100 files on the call to Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to get a list of all the files from a Google Drive account using Google Drive API. There must be a problem since I keep getting the same 100 first files on every call even if I change the service pageToken for the nextPageToken got on the result. Been a lot of time working on it but I have no more ideas about what's the mistake. Can someone help?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    //Global variable of a Drive service getting started
    service = getDriveService();
    //Creating the Filelist with the execution of the service
    FileList result = service.files().list()
            .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name, permissions)")
            .execute();
    //Variable to know how many results we've got
    int count = 0;
    List<File> files = null;

    System.out.println("Files:");
    while (result.getNextPageToken() != null)
    {
        files = result.getFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            System.out.println("File name: "+file.getName()+
                    "\nFile id: "+file.getId()+
                    "\nPermissions: "+file.getPermissions()+
                    "\nRevisions: ");
            count++;
        }
        result = getNextFiles(result);
    }

    if (files == null || files.size() == 0) {
        System.out.println("No more files found.");
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}

private static FileList getNextFiles (FileList result)
{
    try {
        //Changing the pageToken from the service to execute and get next results
        service.files().list().setPageToken(result.getNextPageToken());
        return service.files().list().execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Modified the last method with two system.out to see the pageToken outputs like this:

```
private static FileList getNextFiles (FileList result)
{
    try {
        //Changing the pageToken from the service to execute and get next results

        System.out.println("Actual token: "+service.files().list().getPageToken());
        service.files().list().setPageToken(result.getNextPageToken());
        System.out.println("Supposed next page token: "+result.getNextPageToken());
        System.out.println("After adding the page token to the service: "+service.files().list().getPageToken());
        return service.files().list().execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

That's the result, dont know why the service is not getting the page token and even setting it whith the next page token is still null:

Actual token: null

Supposed next page token: V1*3|0|ChwwQjlxU0xvMmJJS05ZWlhNNFUzSXlXVUkwTWpREgcQlKeu5r8r

After adding the page token to the service: null

Actual token: null

Supposed next page token: V1*3|0|ChwwQjlxU0xvMmJJS05ZWlhNNFUzSXlXVUkwTWpREgcQlKeu5r8r

After adding the page token to the service: null

Comment: add a System.out.println(result.getNextPageToken()); to your getNextFiles method and update the question with the output

Comment: Can you perform a console.log/debug to compare if you're really passing 2 different pageTokens?

Comment: Eddited the main question with two souts and the result